# magento 2.4 intercept execute and get saved object id

Tags: magento2.4, after-plugin

I have a frontend controller that submits a form the following way:

- the controller execute method is called
- this method takes the post values from the request, then first creates an empty object, then populates the object with the post values and save the object
- if the `save()` gives no error, then it adds a few comments via the `statusHistory` and send an email
- if everything is fine, it adds a success message via the `messageMenager`, otherwise it redirects to another page, then the method ends with a void return (`return;`)

I need to get the id of saved object. I could extend the original method and add my code just after the part I need but I'd rather try with plugins/observer first. My problem in this case is that I don't know how to get the ObjectId since  it's not returned by the execute method.

The original Submit class looks like this:

```
public function execute()
{
  try {
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    // does other stuff
    $newObject = $this->buildNewObject($order, $post);
    if (!$newObject->save($post)) {
      $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_redirect->error($url));
      return;
    }

    $statusHistory = $this->statusHistoryFactory->create();
    $statusHistory->setObjectEntityId($newObject->getEntityId());
    $statusHistory->sendNewEmail();
    $statusHistory->saveSystemComment();

    if (isset($post['comment']) && !empty($post['comment'])) {
      /** @var History $comment */
      $comment = $this->statusHistoryFactory->create();
      $comment->setObjectEntityId($newObject->getEntityId());
      $comment->saveComment($post['comment'], true, false);
    }

    // my code can go anywhere after this point, that is: after the code has added the comments and sent the email

    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You Submitted Object #%1.', $newObject->getIncrementId()));
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_redirect->success($this->_url->getUrl('*/*/history')));
    return;
  } catch (\Throwable $e) {
    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__($errorMessage));
    $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_redirect->error($this->_url->getUrl('*/*/history')));
  }
}
```

And this is my plugin:

```
public function afterExecute(
  \Vendor\Module\Controller\Action\Submit $subject, 
  $result
)
{
  // here I get the initial post params
  $post = $subject->getRequest()->getParams();

  // here I need the object id but I don't know how to retrieve the $newObject created during the original execute method
  $objectId = ???

  return $result;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: There's no way you can retrieve the object id since i suppose it's not saved anywhere in the database, what you should probably do if you do not want to extend your observer is to create a custom observer and a dispatch event sending the saved object as parameter

Comment: Hi @AlanZavagli . The object id is saved in the database in  the middle of the execute method but then the method doesn't return the id so I don't know how to get the id (I need the id to get the object, check some data and , in case,  update the object)